# E possível eu gravar uma informação usando user.uid de um no firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-database

Não tenho conhecimento sobre a área, então no momento possuo muitas dúvidas e uma delas é essa:

Possuo um script que a proposta e pegar o user.uid quando ele estiver logado atravez de email e senha do firebase auth e pelo use.uid fazer a gravação do troco no firebase, a estrutura de onde ele deveria ser gravado e a seguinte `users --> user.uid que no banco fica assim: cB9r9Y4zQcZ81cKqPGroA3HDVqi1 --> address ---> troco` porém com as tentativas de amador não to conseguindo fazer essa gravação, minha tentativa foi a seguinte:

```js
// Initialize Firebase (ADD YOUR OWN DATA)
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid).child('address');
// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('trocoForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
// Submit form
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get values
  var troco = getInputVal('troco');
  // Save message
  saveTroco(troco);
  // Show alert
  // por alert aqui
  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('trocoForm').reset();
}
// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
// Save message to firebase
function saveTroco(troco) {
  var newTrocoRef = messagesRef.push();
  newTrocoRef.set({
    troco_id: troco,
  });
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      user.providerData.forEach(function(profile) {
        console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
        console.log("  UID: " + user.uid);
        console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
        console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
      });
    }
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="trocoForm">
  <p class="full">
    <label>Informe seu troco</label>
    <input type="tel" pattern="([0-9]{1,3}\.)?[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{2}$" maxlength="15" name="troco" id="troco"></input>
  </p>
  <p class="full">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p> Exemplo 50,00
</form>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="troco.js"></script>
```

loguei em usuário e rodei um script para ver se conseguia recuperar o user.uid e consegui mas não consigo fazer a gravação por ele, o script usado foi:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  UID: " + user.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
  });
}
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tava faltando apenas isso para o projeto dar certo:

```
if (user) {
    uid=user.uid;
  }
});
```

e editar a linha:

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid).child('address');
```

Para:

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid);
```

E o código ficou assim:

```
// Initialize Firebase (ADD YOUR OWN DATA)
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    uid=user.uid;
    // Reference messages collection
    var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid);
    // Listen for form submit
    document.getElementById('trocoForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
    // Submit form
    function submitForm(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Get values
      var troco = getInputVal('troco');
      // Save message
      saveTroco(troco);
      // Show alert
      // por alert aqui
      // Clear form
      document.getElementById('trocoForm').reset();
    }
    // Function to get get form values
    function getInputVal(id){
      return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    // Save message to firebase
    function saveTroco(troco){
      var newTrocoRef = messagesRef.push();
      newTrocoRef.set({
        troco_id: troco,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Tava faltando eu deixar claro para o código quem era o uid.